# c++ mingw STL installation

Tags: c++, windows, stl, mingw

I recently installed MinGW and MSYS on my Windows 32 machine and it seems to be running fine.

On the C++ compiler, I am including a vector container and getting no errors to that. But I`m getting compile-time errors when I try to use it.

So, the code

```
#include <vector>  // include vector.h  
#include <stdio.h>  // include stdio.h

using namespace std;

main()  {

//   vector<int> A;  

printf("\nHeya ..");

}
```

is running just fine. However, the moment I un-comment line 8-- the vector declaration line, I get the following error (shortened) in compile time:

```
undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'
undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
```

Comment: You're not, by chance, compiling with gcc instead of g++, are you?

Comment: try gcc -std=c++0x program.cpp

Answer (score 9):

You're probably compiling with `gcc` instead of `g++`. The actual compiler is the same, but `g++` tells the linker to use the default C++ libraries, were `gcc` only tells it to look at the C libraries. As soon as you use and C++-specific parts of the standard library, `gcc` will fail.

As an aside, C++ doesn't support the `default int` rule from old C, so you should really specify the return type from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you are compiling your code. Your main method is invalid, incorrect signature and you aren't returning anything.

Should be like this:

```
#include <vector>  // include vector.h  
#include <stdio.h>  // include stdio.h

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)  {

//   vector<int> A;  

printf("\nHeya ..");
return 0;
}
```

Also you need to compile this with g++ and not gcc.

Comment: The only thing that needs to be fixed for main is to add the `int` return type.  The arguments and the actual return statement are not necessary, though not wrong either.

Comment: @Anonymous If I define those variables, the compiler will give me a warning about those variables being unused. Also, why define something that isn't going to be used? I only define argc & argv if I actually use them in main.

Comment: So why not `int main(...)` ??